# Is there any website or software that are like "Guess the move" training program in chesstempo?

Tags: strategy, training

I find the "Guess the move" training program in chesstempo website very helpful. But this is not free and also the number of games is not much (compared to tactics training program which is in the order of hundreds of thousands; while "Guess the move" program contains around 100 games).
Is there any other website or software that is like "Guess the move" training program?

Comment: Chess Tactics Server. Be afraid.  http://chess.emrald.net/

Answer (score 4):

What about the iOS SmallChess app written by myself?

[image]
<sub>(source: [smallchess.com](http://www.smallchess.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/W3_2.jpg))</sub>
[image]
<sub>(source: [smallchess.com](http://www.smallchess.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/W4_2.jpg))</sub>
[image]
<sub>(source: [smallchess.com](http://www.smallchess.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/W5_2.jpg))</sub>
[image]
<sub>(source: [smallchess.com](http://www.smallchess.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/W6_2.jpg))</sub>

Comment: That looks really slick! Is there an Android version in the works?

Comment: @LarryColeman Sorry, only iOS.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Scid](http://scid.sourceforge.net/) for that. You'll need a database of games; for example you could download games from [chessOK](http://chessok.com) or [The Week In Chess](http://theweekinchess.com/) and filter them to use only games between 2400+ players.

Once you have such database you can use the `Play|Training|Review game` functionality and you'll get what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Not free, but I've found that Shredder's tactics training ("Find the best move for White/Black") seems to have an endless supply of such questions (probably only in the thousands in actuality).

The Polgar book "Chess" with 5000+ mating problems is also good, but also not free.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote some free software: GuessTheMove.  YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZgWSCHxJHI. Website: https://sites.google.com/site/fredm/

Comment: Fantastic Idea! Thank you for being so generous! Does it work on Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly the way the "Guess the move" training works in in chesstempo website. 
But chess.com has the "chess mentor", and as far as I know is offered also to free accounts. I pretty much love that one, you can choose from many lessons and they are grouped by categories. What I like is that, if the given board position is too hard for your level or you simply cannot "read" the correct plan, you can choose to ask for up to three tips to guide your thinking on the right track.

I just verified now with a friend having a free account and at least some time ago the chess mentor WAS also available to free accounts - not sure how it is now. It is limited however to the number of problems one can do, even some paid membership can do up to 5 lessons per day.

Answer (score -1):

Try [lichess](http://lichess.org).

It is free and offers tactical positions where you need to find the best next move.